# Cavs vs. Warriors - probability of Cavs winning the series includes combinations like "0,1,0,0,0,1,1" - but the series is over after game 5

Tags: r, probability

There is a problem in DataCamp about computing the probability of winning an NBA series. Cavs and the Warriors are playing a seven game championship series. The first to win four games wins the series. They each have a 50-50 chance of winning each game. If the Cavs lose the first game, what is the probability that they win the series?

Here is how DataCamp computed the probability using **Monte Carlo** simulation:

```
B <- 10000
set.seed(1)
results<-replicate(B,{x<-sample(0:1,6,replace=T) # 0 when game is lost and 1 when won. 
sum(x)>=4})
mean(results)
```

Here is a different way they computed the probability using simple code:

```
# Assign a variable 'n' as the number of remaining games.
n<-6

# Assign a variable `outcomes` as a vector of possible game outcomes: 0 indicates a loss and 1 a win for the Cavs.
outcomes<-c(0,1)

# Assign a variable `l` to a list of all possible outcomes in all remaining games. Use the `rep` function on `list(outcomes)` to create list of length `n`.
l<-rep(list(outcomes),n)

# Create a data frame named 'possibilities' that contains all combinations of possible outcomes for the remaining games.
possibilities<-expand.grid(l) # My comment: note how this produces 64 combinations.

# Create a vector named 'results' that indicates whether each row in the data frame 'possibilities' contains enough wins for the Cavs to win the series.
rowSums(possibilities)
results<-rowSums(possibilities)>=4

# Calculate the proportion of 'results' in which the Cavs win the series. 
mean(results)
```

**Question/Problem:**

They both produce approximately the same probability of winning the series ~ 0.34. However, there seems to be a flaw in the the concept and the code design. For example, the code (sampling six times) allows for combinations such as the following:

```
G2   G3   G4   G5   G6   G7 rowSums
0    0    0    0    0    0      0   # Series over after G4 (Cavs lose). No need for game G5-G7.
0    0    0    0    1    0      1   # Series over after G4 (Cavs lose). Double counting!
0    0    0    0    0    1      1   # Double counting!

...
1    1    1    1    0    0      4   # No need for game G6 and G7.
1    1    1    1    0    1      5   # Double counting! This is the same as 1,1,1,1,0,0.
0    1    1    1    1    1      5   # No need for game G7.
1    1    1    1    1    1      6   # Series over after G5 (Cavs win). Double counting! 

> rowSums(possibilities)
 [1] 0 1 1 2 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6
```

As you can see, these are never possible. After winning the first four of the remaining six games, no more games should be played. Similarly, after losing the first three games of the remaining six games, no more games should be played. So these combinations shouldn't be included in the computation of the probability of winning the series. There is double counting for some of the combinations.

Here is what I did to omit some of the combinations that are not possible in real life.

```
outcomes<-c(0,1)
l<-rep(list(outcomes),6)
possibilities<-expand.grid(l)
possibilities<-possibilities %>% mutate(rowsums=rowSums(possibilities)) %>% filter(rowsums<=4)
```

But then I am not able to omit the other unnecessary combinations. For example, I want to remove two of these three: (a) 1,0,0,0,0,0 (b) 1,0,0,0,0,1 (c) 1,0,0,0,1,1. This is because no more games will be played after losing three times in a row. And they are basically double counting.

There are too many conditions for me to be able to filter them individually. There has to be a more efficient and intuitive way to do this. Can someone provide me with some hints on how to solve this whole mess?

Comment: There’s no need to simulate here. The [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) will give you the answer directly.

Comment: @Limey The exercise is to learn the Monte Carlo and not use other mathematical methods. I want to know how to edit the code to accommodate all the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
library(dplyr)
outcomes<-c(0,1)
l<-rep(list(outcomes),6)
possibilities<-expand.grid(l)
possibilities %>% 
  mutate(rowsums=rowSums(cur_data()),
         anti_sum = rowSums(!cur_data())) %>% 
  filter(rowsums<=4, anti_sum <= 3)
```

We use the fact that [r](/questions/tagged/r) can coerce into a logical where 0 will be false. See `sum(!0)` as a short example.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! Those are the numbers I got doing it by brute force - counting all combinations. Can you tell me what is "cur_data()" doing there really? I looked at the manual but still don't get it ...

Comment: It is whatever is being passed from `%>%`. In this case, it is the same as `possibilities` but I think `cur_data()` is better because in the event you filtered or joined or have something other than the original dataset, `cur_data()` would capture those other options